# Alternative method to print a graph in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, bloom-filter

I try to plot a graph in C having this data structure:

- A bloom filter that rapresent a graph
- A list of all node
- The first node of the graph (in degree == 0)
- An array that contains all node adjacent to another node

I try to print the graph using this method, but it don't start with the known `first node`:

```
file = fopen("out/graph.dot", "w");


fprintf(file, "digraph G {\n");

key_list = hash_table_keys(hash_table);
edge = NULL;
sub_kmer = NULL;

while ( key_list != NULL ) {
  sub_kmer = substr(key_list->key, 1, strlen(key_list->key));
  edge = kmer_append(sub_kmer);

  for ( i = 0; i < NUM_BASE; i++ ) {
    if ( bloom_filter_get(bloom_filter, edge[i]) ) {
      fprintf(file, "  %s ", key_list->key);
      fprintf(file, "-> ");
      fprintf(file, "%s \n", edge[i]);
    }
    free(*(edge + i));
  }

  free(sub_kmer);
  free(edge);

  key_list = key_list->next;
}

fprintf(file, "}");
fclose(file);
```

Where:

- `substr` compute the substring of a string
- `kmer_append` append to the substring the chars (A, C, G, T)
- `bloom_filter_get` check if the node is in the bloom filter

Are There a methods for print the graph using only the `first node`, the `bloom filter` and the `adjacenty array`?

Comment: If you don't start with the node that you want to start, your problem will be here probably: `key_list = hash_table_keys(hash_table);`.  There you are asigning the node that will be printed first

Comment: @CacahueteFrito With this metod, I don't start with the `first node` but I use the list that contains all node of graph. I'm looking for a method that not use the `key_list`

Comment: What is the known first node? And how do you get it?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Since the graph must be Eulerian, I know that there must be only one node with in degree equal to zero. So by using the bloom filter and hanging one of the four letter possibilities (A, C, G, T) at the top of the k-mer substring, you can get the initial node